# Why Xcode doesn't show intellisense for UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiwebview

I just created a Xcode 4 Single View project (without storyboard), drag and drop an UIWebView and then started to type

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface myViewController : UIViewController

    IBOutlet UI...

@end
```

But Xcode Intellisense does only show UIKit and UIViewController and not UIWebView why ? Sorry it's a beginner's question :)

Comment: Maybe Xcode bails out because of the error that is already caused when you try to type this. The `IBOutlet UI...` shouldn't be there at all. You cannot declare variables like this. If you want to put instance variables inside the `@interface` you have to put them into `{}`

Comment: Intellisense is Mircosoft's version of code completion, so strictly speaking, Xcode does not have Intellisense. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because ivars needs to be in brackets.
A regular class/interface in Obj-c should look like

```
@interface CLASSNAME (: PARENTCLASS)
{
   ivars;
}
- (returntype) instance methods/properties;
+ (returntype) class methods;
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you did not include the headers. XCode suggests only identifiers that are in scope.

Comment: Do you mean this #import <UIKit/UIKit.h> ? It is included by Xcode should I include something else ?

Comment: Did you edit? I don't remember to see the `#import` the first time. However, Matthias Bauch is right: `UIWebView` makes no sense here. If you put the parentheses, XCode makes the right suggestions (just tried).

Comment: I made an edit to the question. The line was not correctly indented as code so the `#import` was showing as a header (from the # symbol) with the name import. And the `<UIKit/UIKit.h>` was hidden because it was interpreted as a tag. The `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` was there from the beginning, just not so visible.